# Problemas para instalar la apk en mi celular, cuando intento instalarla me dice que no tengo una aplicación compatible para abrir la aplicación

Tags: flutter, apk, build

Revisando mi proyecto y tratando de encontrar la forma de generar una **apk** que no me diera error en mi móvil, me di cuenta que tengo un error en el **.gradle** de mi computadora.

Aquí genero la **apk**, en la carpeta raíz de mi proyecto

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

Me devuelve esto

```
Building with sound null safety 

Formato de par�metros incorrecto:
```

y esto

```
Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.21/eeb4d60d75e9ea9c11200d52974e522793b14fba/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.21/568c1b78a8e17a4f35b31f0a74e2916095ed74c2/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76ais 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.6.21/eeb4d60d75e9ea9c11200d52974e522793b14fba/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.6.21/568c1b78a8e17a4f35b31f0a74e2916095ed74c2/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21.jar (version 1.6)
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
    C:/Users/Mario Valverde/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar (version 1.7)
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           80,5s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (7.9MB).
```

No tengo ni idea de cual sería la mejor manera de solucionarlo, sin alterar demasiado el proyecto, gracias

Comment: _Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath_. ¿Hiciste lo que dice el mensaje?

Answer (score 0):

Ve a `build.gradle` , en `ext.kotlin_version` debes tener una versión la cual no es compatible con tu proyecto. Prueba a cambiarla a una posterior, por ejemplo:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

a

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

Puedes mirar las versiones [aquí](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details) .